# How to catch bootstrap carousel slider event, when ever it slides?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, carousel

i am a new to vuejs and nuxtjs, I am trying to capture the slider event.
I want to capture the slider event to show the active slide value, can anyone provide me any solution for this, I am working on nuxtjs using b-carousel i.e vuejs bootstrap. Here is my code for the same.

```
        <b-carousel
            ref="myCarousel"
            id="carousel-1"
            v-model="slide"
            :interval=interval
            controls
            indicators
            background="#ababab"
            width="512"
            height="240"
            style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;"
            @sliding-start="onSlideStart"
            @sliding-end="onSlideEnd"
            v-on:change="signalChange"
          >
          <b-carousel-slide
          caption="First slide"
          text="Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum."
          img-src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=52"
          height="200px;"
          v-for="(item, index) in word_list"
            :key="item.words"
            v-bind:class="[
              index == 0 ? 'carousel-item active audio_slider' : 'carousel-item audio_slider',
            ]"
          >
            <div id="carousel-amusement-slider-active" width="100%" height="100%">

                <audio controls id="slider_audio" style="text-align:center" hidden >
                    <source :src="'http://localhost/api/public/Languages/English/'+ item.words + '.mp3'" type="audio/ogg"></source>
                    <source :src="'http://localhost/api/public/Languages/English/'+ item.words + '.mp3'" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
                    
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>
                <div class="amusement-slider-block">
                  <!-- <h5>{{ item.length }}</h5> -->
                  <h5 class="auto-slider-heading">
                    {{ item.parent_name }}
                  </h5>
                  <div class="amusement-slider-wrap">
                    <h6 class="pb-2">{{ item.words }}</h6>
                    <h6 v-if="item.word_with_dot">
                      {{
                        (item1 = item.word_with_dot.replaceAll(
                          "-",
                          "&middot;"
                        ))
                      }}
                    </h6>

                    <h6 class="fw-normal fst-italic my-2">
                      {{ item.word_class }}
                    </h6>
                    <p class="auto_slider_inline auto_slider_def">
                      {{ words_info.definition }}
                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <p class="auto_slider_inline">
                      Also see: {{ item.synonyms }}
                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <p class="auto_slider_inline">
                      "{{ item.word_usage }}"
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
  
            </div>
            </b-carousel-slide>
            </b-carousel>
```

**Target :** I want to watch the slider event to capture its value on change. I want to capture the slider event to show the active slide value, can anyone provide me any solution for this, I am working on nuxtjs using b-carousel i.e vuejs bootstrap. Here is my code for the same.

Comment: Hi, can you target your component with your Vue devtools and inspect it's emitted event?

Comment: Also, your code snippet is not really runable like that, could be nice to have a snippet of data that could make it work. Moreover, you already have `@sliding-start` in your snippet, so that one should work as shown here: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/carousel#comp-ref-b-carousel-events

Comment: hey @kissu thanks for the comment, I got this working via watcher and using javascript functions.
There is another issue that i am facing while using a simple bootstrap carouse...
as below, do you have any idea on this...

jquery_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_default(...)
(...).carousel is not a function

Comment: Hm, I would like to see how you fixed that exactly. You don't need to use any kind of eventListeners (I assume you used those) while working with a framework made for Vue.